# How to send email using Rules from user references CCK Field?

Tags: 7, rules, nodes, emails, users

I have 2 types of content that are: Videos and Customers.

A video can be related only by 1 customer. I want that when a video is created or edited, will send an email to the customer associated with the video.

"Videos" has a Node_reference that is the customer reference. "Customers" have a user_reference referencing the corresponding user.

Then, using Rules for send mail but I don't know how to get the email of the user from the field node_reference from "Videos" to user_reference of "Customers".

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you added the condition "entity has field", then explicit defined your user ref field? Once you do that, in theory you should be able to drill down to user:mail

Comment: You can look into the availables tokens on the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the recipient input, try to write a php code which returns the email :

```
$customer_node = node_load( $node->field_customer['und'][0]['nid'] );
$account = user_load( $customer_node->field_user['und'][0]['uid'] );
print $account->mail;
```

Note that a better way is to use a custom function in a custom module :

```
print _get_customer_email( $node );
```

and

```
function _get_customer_email( $node ){
  $customer_node = node_load( $node->field_customer['und'][0]['nid'] );
  $account = user_load( $customer_node->field_user['und'][0]['uid'] );
  return $account->mail;
}
```

Comment: That is!.. This is the answer!